# jQuery: Image Highlighting

Tags: jquery

This is probably a simple solution but I am just not seeing it. I appreciate the help.

I am following this guide: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/04/image-highlighting-preview/

Guide Demo: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ImageHighlighter/

And here is my code (also below): http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/Xa4f3/9/

Multiple problems:

- It's not showing the zoom, loading, and close icons.
- Overlay is not disappearing when you remove the mouse from over the
  image.
- The image is loading under the "thumbnail".

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.daysofthedead.net/los_angeles/images/guests/coming_soon_sunday_hover.png" alt="http://www.daysofthedead.net/los_angeles/images/guests/coming_soon_sunday_hover.png" class="ih_image" width="510" height="150">
<div id="ih_overlay" class="ih_overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.ih_overlay{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#000;
    z-index:10;
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=90);
}
img.ih_image{
    margin:10px 0px;
    position:relative;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 4px #000;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 4px #000;
    opacity:0.7;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
}
.ih_image_clone_wrap{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:11;
}
.ih_image_clone_wrap span.ih_zoom,
.ih_image_clone_wrap span.ih_loading,
.ih_image_clone_wrap span.ih_close{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    opacity:0.8;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
    z-index:999;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80);
}
.ih_image_clone_wrap span.ih_zoom{
    background:#000 url(http://www.daysofthedead.net/images/ih/zoom.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.ih_image_clone_wrap span.ih_loading{
    background:#000 url(http://www.daysofthedead.net/images/ih/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
.ih_image_clone_wrap span.ih_close{
    background:#000 url(http://www.daysofthedead.net/images/ih/close.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.ih_image_clone_wrap img{
    opacity:0.7;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 10px #000;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 10px #000;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
}
.ih_image_clone_wrap img.ih_preview{
    opacity:1;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}​
```

​JS:

```
/**
 * timeout to control the display of the overlay/highlight
 */
var highlight_timeout;

/**
 * user hovers one image:
 * create a absolute div with the same image inside,
 * and append it to the body
 */
$('img.ih_image').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var $thumb = $(this);

    var $clone = $('<div />', {
        'id': 'ih_clone',
        'className': 'ih_image_clone_wrap',
        'html': '<img src="' + $thumb.attr('src') + '" alt="' + $thumb.attr('alt') + '"/><span class="ih_zoom"></span>',
        'style': 'top:' + $thumb.offset().top + 'px;left:' + $thumb.offset().left + 'px;'
    });

    var highlight = function() {
        $('#ih_overlay').show();
        $('BODY').append($clone);
    }
    //show it after some time ... 
    highlight_timeout = setTimeout(highlight, 700);

    /**
     * when we click on the zoom, 
     * we display the image in the center of the window,
     * and enlarge it to the size of the real image, 
     * fading this one in, after the animation is over.
     */
    $clone.find('.ih_zoom').bind('click', function() {
        var $zoom = $(this);
        $zoom.addClass('ih_loading').removeClass('ih_zoom');
        var imgL_source = $thumb.attr('alt');

        $('<img class="ih_preview" style="display:none;"/>').load(function() {
            var $imgL = $(this);
            $zoom.hide();
            var windowW = $(window).width();
            var windowH = $(window).height();
            var windowS = $(window).scrollTop();

            $clone.append($imgL).animate({
                'top': windowH / 2 + windowS + 'px',
                'left': windowW / 2 + 'px',
                'margin-left': -$thumb.width() / 2 + 'px',
                'margin-top': -$thumb.height() / 2 + 'px'
            }, 400, function() {
                var $clone = $(this);
                var largeW = $imgL.width();
                var largeH = $imgL.height();
                $clone.animate({
                    'top': windowH / 2 + windowS + 'px',
                    'left': windowW / 2 + 'px',
                    'margin-left': -largeW / 2 + 'px',
                    'margin-top': -largeH / 2 + 'px',
                    'width': largeW + 'px',
                    'height': largeH + 'px'
                }, 400).find('img:first').animate({
                    'width': largeW + 'px',
                    'height': largeH + 'px'
                }, 400, function() {
                    var $thumb = $(this);
                    /**
                     * fade in the large image. Replace the zoom with a cross,
                     * so the user can close the preview mode
                     */
                    $imgL.fadeIn(function() {
                        $zoom.addClass('ih_close').removeClass('ih_loading').fadeIn(function() {
                            $(this).bind('click', function() {
                                $clone.remove();
                                clearTimeout(highlight_timeout);
                                $('#ih_overlay').hide();
                            });
                        });
                        $thumb.remove();
                    });
                });
            });
        }).error(function() {
            /**
             * error loading image. Maybe show a message : 'no preview available'?
             */
            $zoom.fadeOut();
        }).attr('src', imgL_source);
    });
}).bind('mouseleave', function() {
    /**
     * the user moves the mouse out of an image.
     * if there's no clone yet, clear the timeout
     * (user was probably scolling through the article, and 
     * doesn't want to view the image)
     */
    if ($('#ih_clone').length) return;
    clearTimeout(highlight_timeout);
});

/**
 * the user moves the mouse out of the clone.
 * if we don't have yet the cross option to close the preview, then
 * clear the timeout
 */
$('#ih_clone').live('mouseleave', function() {
    var $clone = $('#ih_clone');
    if (!$clone.find('.ih_preview').length) {
        $clone.remove();
        clearTimeout(highlight_timeout);
        $('#ih_overlay').hide();
    }
});​
```

Comment: I added my code to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another look and there was one change which indeed seemed to have made a lot of difference.

When making the clone you specified one of the settings to be
`'className': ih_image_clone_wrap',`

Replace that with:
`'class': 'ih_image_clone_wrap',`

See full code:

```
var $clone = $('<div />', {
    'id': 'ih_clone',
    'class': 'ih_image_clone_wrap',
    'html': '<img src="' + $thumb.attr('src') + '" alt="' + $thumb.attr('alt') + '"/><span class="ih_zoom"></span>',
    'style': 'top:' + $thumb.offset().top + 'px;left:' + $thumb.offset().left + 'px;'
});
```

In addition the image size difference will be fixed if you remove the `width` and `height` settings from the original `img` tag as you mentioned in the comments.

If you want it to be 510 x 150 just apply the same to your clone and you are good to go.

Unless I'm mistaken this seemed to have fixed all issues:

- It's not showing the zoom, loading, and close icons (fixed)
- Overlay is not disappearing when you remove the mouse from over the image (fixed)
- The image is loading under the "thumbnail" (fixed)

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xa4f3/26/)

Hope this helped.

Comment: I have to assume the problem is something else that is effecting all three things since the Demo uses `#ih_clone` and it works just fine.

Comment: @Draven: The reason it works in the DEMO is because the overlay doesn't cover the image you hover over, hence the `mouseleave` can be triggered there. Your overlay is covering the full-screen instead so your mouse-pointer cannot trigger `mouseleave` on the original image. I have another look.

Comment: I believe it's because I am using width and height in the `img` tag

Comment: Found another problem, it's the version of jQuery that is messing things up too :(

Comment: @Draven: `I have to assume the problem is something else that is effecting all three things` and you were correct :) Simply fixing class setting in the clone from `className` to `class` seems to have done it. I updated the answer and added the corrected DEMO. I also added a note regarding your comment on the image size.